# Html5 canvas drawImage leaves empty lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw, drawimage

I am trying to draw an 8K image on the canvas. The player is always in the middle of the screen and the image is the background of the entire map which is 5000x5000px. I am cropping the image to show only the player's viewport:

`sDrawX = player.x - (canvas.width / 2); // x pos to start cropping
 sDrawY = player.y - (canvas.height / 2); // y pos to start cropping
 ctx.drawImage(bkg, sDrawX, sDrawY, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

The problem is that every time it draws the image, empty lines are visible on the canvas. I figured out that these lines have the canvas background color.

Image: [vertical white line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boUBb.jpg)

Image 2 : [both vertical and horizontal white lines at different positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FykFD.jpg)

Since I am drawing the image every frame, do you think it;s possible that it can't draw it all each frame?

After some more debugging : it works on images with smaller resolution.

Comment: Seems very strange. There is no restriction for drawing image every frame. And code also looks good. Could you write more information?

Comment: Well, i think this is all. I am not drawing anything else besides the player, which is ok. I tried to animate other spritesheets the same way and it worked perfectly.

Comment: It seam to me that those lines are transparent, and that's why you see canvas color. Did you make sure that your image is not transparent?

Comment: Yes, I checked 2 images from google. Same.

Comment: Have you tried your app in different browsers?

Comment: No, just google chrome. I'll go ahead and try it on others!

Comment: That looks like antialiasing. Check that you are always cropping and drawing on plain pixel.